# Why is RestKit returning a different response than NSURLConnection

Tags: json, cocoa-touch, yaml, restkit

I am using RestKit in a project and was getting an unexpected response '---', so I tried to use a standard NSURLConnection but I got the correct response - a json formatted string. Can any one figure out what is the difference between these two requests? If it makes a different the content-type is "text/yaml" for the response.

Here is the RKRequest version which returns '---'

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL_STRING];
RKRequest *request = [RKRequest requestWithURL:URL delegate:self];
request.queue = [RKClient sharedClient].requestQueue;
request.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTP;
request.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
request.params = requestParams;
[request send];
```

Here is the NSURLConnection version which returns an appropriately formatted response in json/yaml.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL_STRING];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                               timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[requestParams UTF8String] 
                                     length:[requestParams length]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
```

UPDATE:

Okay, now things are getting really weird - it stopped working completely for both the NSURLConnection and RestKit. If anyone can help it would be appreciated, here is the cURL that I use threw the terminal to verify results (this still works).

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{"username":"username","password":"password"}' http://example.com/login
```

And my requestParams is @"{\"username\":\"username\",\"password\":\"password\"}"